# How to keep Bootstrap tooltip after changing element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this part of my JavaScript (jQuery code)

```
        instance.on(dragLinks, "click", function(e) {
            var s = instance.toggleDraggable(this.getAttribute("rel"));
            this.innerHTML = (s ? '<a href="#" class="cmdLink drag" style="margin-right: 3px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" title="disable dragging" style="font-size: 15px;"> </span> </a>' : '<a href="#" class="cmdLink drag" style="margin-right: 3px;"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" title="enable dragging" style="font-size: 15px;"> </span> </a>');              
            jsPlumbUtil.consume(e);
        });
```

Line that starts with 'this.innerHTML' make changes on elements (icons) after clicking on them. As you can see, it is bootstrap 3.0 glyphicons.

I have tooltip on them

```
        $(".glyphicon-remove-sign").tooltip({ 
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    });
        $(".glyphicon-ok-sign").tooltip({
                placement: 'bottom',
                });
```

After loading of application the glyphicon-remove-sign icon is first shown. The Bootstrap 3.0 tooltip is also shown correctly. But, the problem is that after clicking on them, there is no more Bootstrap 3.0 tooltip effect, only poor HTML tooltip. How to resolve this?

Comment: Rofl. you must re-initialise tooltip.

Comment: Thank you very much Miraage! I forgot what I have to do. I resolve it with $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap website, "a tooltip and popover data-apis are opt in, meaning you must initialize them yourself."

Therefore, to achieve your goal, one must re-initialize the bootstrap tooltip, as mentioned by Miraage.

Here is a nice tutorial that may help:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tooltips.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why are you citing the v2 docs when the question is about v3?